# When i click navigation tabs it will not active . Why ? It will active when i click two time . But one click it will route to respective page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="os-tabs-w">
            <div class="os-tabs-controls os-tabs-complex">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-s-home" :class="dashboardTheme" @click="created('dash')"
                            href="#/helpdesk" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tab-label">DashBoard</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-s-ticket" :class="ticketTheme" href="#/helpdesk/tickets"
                            @click="created('ticket')" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tab-label">Tickets</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-circle-close nav-actions" :class="completeTheme"
                            href="#/helpdesk/completed_tickets" @click="created('complete')" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                class="tab-label">Completed Tickets</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-s-help" :class="tatTheme" href="#/helpdesk/tat_tickets"
                            @click="created('tat')" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tab-label">TAT Tickets</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-s-custom" :class="configTheme" href="#/helpdesk/tickets_config"
                            @click="created('config')" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tab-label">Ticket
                                Config</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-coin" :class="slaTheme" href="#/helpdesk/tickets_sla"
                            @click="created('sla')" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tab-label">Ticket SLA</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link el-icon-coin" :class="ruleTheme" href="#/helpdesk/tickets_rules"
                            @click="created('rule')" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tab-label">Ticket Rules</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my html coding . I use dynamic class to active the navigation tabs. If any method better than this please suggest me . It would help me a lot

```html
    <script>
        export default {
          mounted(){
            this.created("dash");
          },
          data() {
            return {
              dashboardTheme: "",
              ticketTheme:"",
              completeTheme:"",
              tatTheme:"",
              configTheme:"",
              slaTheme:"",
              ruleTheme:"",
            };
          },
          methods: {
            created(ticvalue) {
              if (ticvalue == "dash") {
                this.dashboardTheme = "active",
                this.ticketTheme = "",
                this.completeTheme='',
                this.tatTheme='',
                this.configTheme='',
                this.slaTheme='',
                this.ruleTheme=''
              } else if (ticvalue == "ticket") {
                this.dashboardTheme = "",
                this.ticketTheme = "active",
                this.completeTheme='',
                this.tatTheme='',
                this.configTheme='',
                this.slaTheme='',
                this.ruleTheme=''
              } else if (ticvalue == "complete") {
                console.log("complr")
                this.dashboardTheme = "",
                this.ticketTheme = ""
                this.completeTheme="active";
                this.tatTheme='',
                this.configTheme='',
                this.slaTheme='',
                this.ruleTheme=''
              } else if (ticvalue == "tat") {
                this.dashboardTheme = '',
                this.ticketTheme = '',
                this.completeTheme='',
                this.tatTheme='active',
                this.configTheme='',
                this.slaTheme='',
                this.ruleTheme=''
              } else if (ticvalue == "config") {
                this.dashboardTheme = '',
                this.ticketTheme = '',
                this.completeTheme='',
                this.tatTheme='',
                this.configTheme='active',
                this.slaTheme='',
                this.ruleTheme=''
              } else if (ticvalue == "sla") {
                this.dashboardTheme = '',
                this.ticketTheme = '',
                this.completeTheme='',
                this.tatTheme='',
                this.configTheme='',
                this.slaTheme='active',
                this.ruleTheme=''
              } else if (ticvalue == "rule") {
                this.dashboardTheme = '',
                this.ticketTheme = ''
                this.completeTheme='',
                this.tatTheme='',
                this.configTheme='',
                this.slaTheme='',
                this.ruleTheme='active'
              }
            }
          }
        };
     </script>
```

this is my script . Here i use `active` to highlight the tab . I tried so many possibilities But i won't get answer for this. Someone help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue's event modifier `.prevent` on your `@click` calls:

Change your `@click="..."` calls to `@click.prevent="..."` in your code.

This will prevent the default behavior (follow a link) of the click event.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Bro Now it will work But i can't redirect to respective page .